# Update a Table using a Join

Tags: sql, firebird, firebird2.5

I wish to update a table using, but need to use another table to get the correct field. The new information is not taken from another field from another table.

The following SQL statement returns the correct information:

```
SELECT PURCHASEHEADER.ORDERNOTES
FROM PURCHASEHEADER, ASSEMBLYLINESOURCE
WHERE ASSEMBLYLINESOURCE.HEADERSYSUNIQUEID = 72637001
  AND PURCHASEHEADER.ORDERNUMBER = ASSEMBLYLINESOURCE.PURCHASEORDERNUMBER
```

I have tried the following:

```
UPDATE PURCHASEHEADER SET PURCHASEHEADER.ORDERNOTES = 'Updated'
WHERE EXISTS (
   SELECT 1 FROM ASSEMBLYLINESOURCE 
   WHERE PURCHASEHEADER.ORDERNUMBER = ASSEMBLYLINESOURCE.PURCHASEORDERNUMBER
) AND ASSEMBLYLINESOURCE.HEADERSYSUNIQUEID = 72637001
```

An error is returned saying: " ...Column Unknown `ASSEMBLYLINESOURCE.HEADERSYSUNIQUEID`..." but it does exist as it works in the first query.

I have seen similar posts from Mark Rotteveel dated July 2017, but still can't get it to work.

Comment: you do not seem to format your sources. Why? I just spent 15 seconds to make sources readable and representing the structure - and didn't it become obvious now your UPDATE command had inverted the structure inside out, referencing inside tables from outside where and referencing only outside tables from inside ?

Answer (score 1):

There is an issue with your closing bracket. Try this, it worked for me.

```
UPDATE PURCHASEHEADER set PURCHASEHEADER.ORDERNOTES = 'Updated'
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM ASSEMBLYLINESOURCE WHERE    
PURCHASEHEADER.ORDERNUMBER = ASSEMBLYLINESOURCE.PURCHASEORDERNUMBER AND  
ASSEMBLYLINESOURCE.HEADERSYSUNIQUEID = 72637001)
```

Comment: What does the Select 1 part mean?

Comment: @SimonKing The select 1 is already in the code in your question. In any case, it means produce column with literal value `1` for each row found. `exists` is just interested in the presence of one or more rows, not in its value.

Comment: Yeh thats correct and updates the PURCHASEHEADER.ORDERNOTES column those belongs to the row returned.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I think implementing it with MERGE would be more efficient though, making a continuous stream over A-L-S table instead of multiple one-row shots at it :-D